# Multiple windows are opening on Windows.open

Tags: javascript, window.open

I have below code in a javascript file,

```
 var windo = window.open("", "");
 windo.document.write("sdhfsdfsfsdkjks image");
```

On clicking a button I am executing above code. But it is opening 2 new tabs, one with content, 'sdhfsdfsfsdkjks image' which is expected and in another tab, it is opening the parent page where I have above code. So anybody has an idea, why it is opening parent page again in the new tab.

Comment: because your calling it in the first instance and again in the second

Comment: could you share more code, click event etc.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you need to cache te window in a global variable, it is browser specific ( If you call open later with the same name, the browser may replace the existing window by a new one. Some browsers (FF) do it, some browsers (IE) open new windows).

Did you think of a solution that dont need a window.open but replace this div content with a Ajax call?

```
var mywindow;
function openFile() {
    if (typeof mywindow == "undefined") {
        mywindow = open("", "_blank"); 
    }
    mywindow.document.write("sdhfsdfsfsdkjks image"); 
}
```

http://javascript.info/tutorial/popup-windows

Comment: I tried adding name and URL also, but still same issue.

Comment: please show the smallest piece of working code with the problem. Then I can say more about this issue

Comment: This is the code, 
function openFile() {
    var windo = window.open("/Scheduled.aspx", "Scheduled");
    windo.document.write("sdhfsdfsfsdkjks image");
}

$("#btnOpen").click(openFile)

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the code

> return false;

when I was calling above openFile() method in anchor tag. That it is reason, it was opening extra tab.Below is working code,

```
 <a onclick="openFile();return false;" href="#">
 function openFile() {
if (typeof mywindow == "undefined") {
    mywindow = open("", "_blank"); 
}
    mywindow.document.write("sdhfsdfsfsdkjks image"); 
}
```